# PHP - Login With Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

The project I am working requires to have a "Login With Facebook" and there is a syntax error in the code I wrote and I tried to find the mistake but I don't think there is any. Can anyone scan it and see if there's something wrong. Thanks!

```
    /* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILES */
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' ); 
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/AccessToken.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
        require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

    /* USE NAMESPACES */

        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
        use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
        use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
        use Facebook\GraphObject;
        use Facebook\GraphUser;
        use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
        use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
        use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
        use Facebook\FacebookCurl;


    /* PROCESS */

        session_start();

        $app_id = '';
        $app_secret = '';
        $redirect_url = '';


        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
        $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

        if(isset($sess)){

            $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET','/me');

            $response = $request->execute();
            $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());

            $name = $graph->getName();
            echo "hi $name";

        }else{

            echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'">Login with facebook</a>'

        }

?>
```

Comment: We should even guess which is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a ; at the end of your echo statement. Hence the error.

so in the last else statement rewrite to:

```
}else{

    echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'">Login with facebook</a>';
 }
?>
```